# .NET 4.0 project templates in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-sdk

I'm creating a set of project templates for my team. We use Visual Studio 2012, but haven't migrated our solutions to .net 4.5 yet. I've installed the Visual Studio SDK for VS2012, but it seems it only installed the "Project template" and "VSIX project" templates for .net 4.5. Is there a way to create 4.0 versions in Visual Studio 2012?